# Unable to save buffered videos using terminal after update to 16.04

Tags: command-line, video, flash

For the last 5 or 6 years using Ubuntu I was able to save buffered videos using the Terminal. I would wait for the video to finish playing and without closing the browser window I would run from the command line:

```
lsof | grep Flash
```

...which shows the files (even memory files!), and filters to those that have Flash in their name. You would get something like this for example:

> plugin-co 2461 user 17u REG 8,5 1693301 524370 /tmp/FlashXXVkHEM6 (deleted)

...then I would get the 4 or 5 digits of the process ID, in this case/example is "2461"

Then I run

```
cd /proc/2461/fd
```

...and then `ls -l`

This will show you the memory files, and in this example:

> lrwx------ 1 user user 64 2011-09-16 10:23 17 -> /tmp/FlashXXVkHEM6 (deleted)

Now, in this example the number 17 is the filename you can use to access the "deleted" file "/tmp/FlashXXVkHEM6" so you can run (code)

```
cp 17 /tmp/whatever_you_name_the_video.flv
```

...and you'll save a copy of that video in your /tmp directory for further use!

But now and here is my question, with 16.04 when I run (code)

```
lsof | grep Flash
```

...And I only get:

> lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
>         Output information may be incomplete.

Is anybody else experiencing this?
How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems like this is only one method of saving Flash video that has been broken in 16. I still can't find one that works. (Preferably through the command line.)